# How to bootstrap a (spatial) lag operator?

Tags: time-series, maximum-likelihood, bootstrap, spatial

In relation with this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/287876/how-to-compute-the-likelihoods-jacobian-of-a-bootstrapped-spatial-autoregressiv) of mine, which goes beyond what I am asking now.

Say one has the following [data generating process (DGP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_generating_process) *(known as the SAR ou spatial lag model in the literature)*:

$\boldsymbol{y} = \rho \boldsymbol{W}\boldsymbol{y} + \boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{\beta} + \boldsymbol{u}$

where $\boldsymbol{y}$ is a $n \times 1$ endogenous vector, $\boldsymbol{X}$ an exogenous $n \times k$ matrix, $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ a $k \times 1$ vector of coefficients, $\boldsymbol{W}$ a $n \times n$ spatial lag operator, $\rho$ a scalar coefficient of autoregression and $\boldsymbol{u}$ a vector of errors, wished iid normal.

---

How would you bootstrap $\boldsymbol{W}$ ? In the case of time series, assume that one has

$$
\boldsymbol{y}  = \begin{pmatrix} 
2013 \\
2014 \\
2015 \\
2016 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

and the following backshift (linear) operator

$$
\boldsymbol{W}  = \begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Let's denote the [(block) bootstrapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)#Block_bootstrap) resampling process by an operator, say, $\mathcal{B}(.)$. What does one do in the times series case ?

$\mathcal{B}(\boldsymbol{W}\boldsymbol{y})$

OR

$\mathcal{B}(\boldsymbol{W})\boldsymbol{y}$ *(equivalent to the previous one if one bootstraps only over the rows of $\boldsymbol{W}$)*

OR

$\boldsymbol{W}\mathcal{B}(\boldsymbol{y})$

OR none of those

***?***

I would say $\mathcal{B}(\boldsymbol{W}\boldsymbol{y})$ but this has weird implications in space when computing the likelihood (cf my [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/287876/how-to-compute-the-likelihoods-jacobian-of-a-bootstrapped-spatial-autoregressiv)). But let us forget these weird implications for a moment. **What do we do in the time series case ?**

*...One of these weird implications is that $\boldsymbol{W}$ may not be [hollow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollow_matrix) anymore if one only resamples its rows...*

---

A python toy-example

```
import numpy as np

W = np.zeros((4,4))
W[1,0] = 1. 
W[2,1] = 1. 
W[3,2] = 1.

y = np.arange(2013,2017).reshape((4,1))
Wy= np.dot(W,y)

def B(obj):
    """
    Operator which only resamples rows
     In the case in which rows and columns are resampled
     we would do:
      return obj[idxs].T[idxs].T # (right ?)
    """
    idxs = [2,3,0,1]
    return obj[idxs]

print B(Wy)
print np.dot(B(W),y)
print np.dot(W,B(y))
```

---

python toy-example which shows that $\mathcal{B}(\boldsymbol{W})$ is not hollow

```
import numpy as np
from random import random as rd

W = np.array([[0.  ,0.,0.,0.],
              [rd(),0.  ,0.,0.],
              [rd(),rd(),0.  ,0.],
              [rd(),rd(),rd(),0.]])
W += W.T                       #to make W be symmetric
print B(W)                     #not hollow !!!    
print B(B(W).T).T              #while B(B(W).T).T is !
```

---

#### Update

[Optimal block size for variance estimation by a spatial block bootstrap](https://www.jstor.org/stable/25664573?seq=1) is very likely to help me out.